# Mouse speed too fast

Tags: mouse, xinput

I've a problem with the mouse speed... I have a gaming mouse with a hardware switch (1000 dpi, 1600 dpi, 2000 dpi) and I've set it to 1000 dpi, I've mouse acceleration and threshold set to 0. I tried solving with xset and xinput but it seemed to don't work at all. I don't know how to set mouse sensitivity under the min... Please help!
Running Ubuntu 15.04 x86;
mouse: Redragon Centrophorus;
Thanks in advance.

---

[I had a look to: manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man4/mousedrv.4.html , I found this (click me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkNtz.png)

the second is what i've already tried (and doesn't work) anyone know how to use the first option?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. Open a terminal
2. Run the command: `xinput --list --short`

> Logitech USB Optical Mouse id=10 [slave pointer (2)]

(this is a part of output you will see, I found the name of my mouse `Logitech USB Optical Mouse`)

3. Note the name of your device.
4. Set the constant deceleration for the device:

> xinput --set-prop "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" "Device Accel Constant
> Deceleration" 5

You need to play with with number, here 5. **Don't loose focus of your terminal because mouse speed may become either too fast or too slow**. **lower the number the faster it will be, similarly, higher the number slower it will be**. For me `1` is too fast, and `100` is too slow.

5. To see the current settings for the device:

> xinput --list-props "Logitech USB Optical Mouse"

If this didn't work for you, you can always revert it back like this:

```
xinput --set-prop "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 1
xinput --set-prop "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" "Device Accel Profile" -1
```

[reference](https://patrickmn.com/aside/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/)

Comment: its better to use ID instead of device label (name ) and It works, Good answer, thumbs up to U

Comment: Very important: when writing commands to a startup file, field names should be used because device ids can change dynamically (c.f. https://askubuntu.com/questions/938589/mouse-speed-too-fast-i-can-change-it-with-xinput-but-how-can-i-make-the-chang).

Comment: Depending on the speed/acceleration property name (xinput --list-props "DEVICE NAME") you may be have to use the property "libinput Accel Speed": xinput set-prop "DEVICE NAME" "libinput Accel Speed" -1

Answer (score 5):

For a Corsair M65 gaming mouse i did the following

`$xinput --list --short
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair M65 Gaming Mouse          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair M65 Gaming Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair M65 Gaming Mouse          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Metadot - Das Keyboard Das Keyboard       id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Metadot - Das Keyboard Das Keyboard       id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair M65 Gaming Mouse          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]`

So my mouse id i 9. 
I get registers associated with this mouse:

```
    $ xinput --list-props 9
Device Corsair Corsair M65 Gaming Mouse:
    Device Enabled (149):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (151): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (286):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (287):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (288):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (289):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (290):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (291): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (292): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (293):    1
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (294):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (295): 0
    libinput Accel Speed Default (296): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (297):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (298):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (299):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (300): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (301): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (271): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (272):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (273):    0, 0
    Device Node (274):  "/dev/input/event3"
    Device Product ID (275):    6940, 6917
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (302):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (303):   1
```

And i set the libinput Accel Speed (295) to -1 to slow it down.

```
$xinput -set-prop 9 295 -1
```

I then just added this to start-up applications.

Comment: thanks so much for sharing! this is what finally worked for my Elecom trackball

Answer (score 4):

I ended up having to do

```
xinput --list --short
```

as said by original answerer, but had to do

```
xinput set-prop 17(my device id) "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 2
```

to make it work on my Xubuntu 16.04 setup, because i have multiple devices matching 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1' ..

Answer (score 3):

If `ConstantDeceleration` is not available, you can use negative accelerations.

In Debian XFCE I used:

```
xinput set-prop 8 "libinput Accel Speed" -0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

This morning my mouse must have drunk too much coffee.  I tried to sedate it via `System Setting | Mouse & Touchpad` but it had absolutely no effect.
The question & answers here were helpful to me.  I describe my own experience which might be useful to others:

---

Some relevant online documentation: 
https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration
says the following:

> Scenarios
>
> If your mouse moves far too fast, ?ConstantDeceleration is your
>   friend. Set to 2 or higher to divide speed accordingly. This will not
>   discard precision (at least only on nv-reset, see Velocity
>   approximation or below).
>
> If your high-performance device does not repond well to acceleration,
>   you might need to reduce velocity scaling first.
>
> If you like the speed but need some more control at pixel-level, you
>   should set ?AdaptiveDeceleration to 2 or more. This allows to
>   decelerate slow movements down to the given factor. You might want to
>   keep nv-resets away by setting ?VelocityReset to e.g. 500 ms, and
>   maybe tweak velocity scaling to tune results.

Step 1 - Find the device id: (as in @edward-torvalds answer)

```
(lf-env) craig@craig-desktop:~/work/leaflet-1$ xinput --list --short
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer
```

My mouse is id==11, this number can be used for setting properties.  Field names can also be used.  *When writing commands to a startup file, field names should be used because device ids can change dynamically (c.f.  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938589/mouse-speed-too-fast-i-can-change-it-with-xinput-but-how-can-i-make-the-chang) ).*

Step 2 - Find the current device settings and the property id numbers:

```
(lf-env) craig@craig-desktop:~/work/leaflet-1$ xinput -list-props 11
Device 'MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse':
    ...
    Device Accel Profile (262): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (263):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (264):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (265):    10.000000
    ...
```

The properties I finally decided to adjust are as follows:

```
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (263):   [original value 1.0]
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (264):   [original value 1.0]
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (265):            [original value 100.0]
```

The online documentation mentioned above gives descriptions of these values.  Here I add some description based on subjective "feeling" and that documentation.

- Device Accel Constant Deceleration (263):
  -- Mouse sensitivity.  Lower settings are slower.  Feels like mouse velocity is divided by this factor.
- Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (264):
  -- When mouse is moving at low speeds, the velocity is further divided by this factor.  The overall feeling is having two seperate gears, lo-gear and high-gear.  In my personal case, I got the best result by matching the settings with a physiological gearing:  for lo-gear my palm-heel is down and I am making fine mouse movements with my finger muscles.  For high gear, my palm-heel is up or sliding and I am making broad movements with arm muscles while gripping the mouse firmly.  It can be a little tricky controlling the transition - if there were another input to tell whether the palm-heel was up/sliding or down/fixed it would be perfect!
- Device Accel Velocity Scaling (265): 
  -- This factor divides the raw numerical data, acting like "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" but also throwing away integer resolution. ? Maybe.

My current settings are as follows:

```
(lf-env) craig@craig-desktop:~/work/leaflet-1$ xinput -set-prop 11 263 10
(lf-env) craig@craig-desktop:~/work/leaflet-1$ xinput -set-prop 11 264 1000
(lf-env) craig@craig-desktop:~/work/leaflet-1$ xinput -set-prop 11 265 10

(lf-env) craig@craig-desktop:~/work/leaflet-1$ xinput -list-props 11
Device 'MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse':
...
    Device Accel Profile (262): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (263):   10.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (264):   1000.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (265):    10.000000
...
```