# Mouse speed too fast - I can change it with xinput, but how can I make the change persistent?

Tags: mouse, xinput

The mouse speed on my computer is too fast. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

I followed the instructions here: 
[Mouse speed too fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688270/mouse-speed-too-fast/690732#690732)

And it worked, except every time I restart my computer I now need to re run that command. If it helps I am dual booting with windows 10 which means I restart my computer quite frequently. Where can I set the default value for the xinput prop so I get the settings I want on startup?

Comment: how about system settings>mouse & touchpad?

Comment: @Toonis - This morning I noticed my mouse sensitivity was way too high although it had been fine some time earlier - not sure of the reason but I installed a lot of software yesterday.  Of course the first thing I tried was adjusting the mouse via the settings menu but it had absolutely no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can put that command mentioned here [Mouse speed too fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688270/mouse-speed-too-fast/690732#690732) at the end of `~/.profile` will run the command automatically when you login into your system.

Run `sudo nano ~/.profile` to be able to edit it. Add the command at the end, save the file and exit. It should work correctly.

For further information about running a command on startup:

[How to run a command at login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270049/how-to-run-a-command-at-login)